# How to change constant strings in app from server without updating the entire app?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a certain use-case problem that I am looking solution for.

Say in a text view I am displaying text like "Welcome Adam!". In general we store this text in `strings.xml` file.
Now I want to update what is shown in the text view from the server without needing to update the entire app.

Ex, "Welcome Adam!" to "Hello Adam!".

What should be my approach in designing a solution?

Comment: rather than storing that string values in strings.xml, get value from web services and display response on textview.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37496454/is-it-possible-to-update-string-xml-file-at-run-time-in-android

Comment: You can have a look at Firebase RemoteConfig

Comment: That text can be a large string, like a paragraph. Also that will not change very frequently. Using web service to load it every time will cause the entire paragraph to load every time. Can I go with push messaging and store the text somewhere?

Comment: you should create Database Table to keep all your strings with keys and its Language  fire query with keys and language .

Comment: How will I incorporate dynamic values in that? Like showing the user's name in place of a placeholder?

Comment: @LearnPainLess That way I'll have to download entire paragraph every time. The paragraph will not be changed frequently. Also how will I add localisation support?

Answer (score 0):

- One url provided by EndPoint.
- Fetch this url and read its response while app launching.
- Set string in response to screen.

Comment: That way I'll have to download entire paragraph every time. The paragraph will not be changed frequently. Also how will I add localisation support?

Answer (score 0):

You cant change string, color, dimen etc xml file during runtime. I think what you are looking for is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27775523/4035641)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it by "formatted string".For example , store "%1$s Adam!" in strings.xml, and write code like String welcome=context.getString(R.string.welcome,"Welcome").You can replace the first string with specified word if you want.
For more information ,refer to [AndroidDev](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)

Comment: If you don't want to adopt the API approach - This can be one of your options. You can update the new string from your server using Firebase Remote Config.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/android